# Creating Let's Encrypt Certificate & Certbot Within Docker Image

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, nginx

I have a Vue.js application that runs with Nginx in a docker image. I have followed some tutorials but none of them was helpful for my case to apply Let's Encrypt certification. How can I create a certificate within my docker file with my configuration?

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

RUN apk add --update nginx nodejs

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/nginx/web
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

COPY nginx_config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx_config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /tmp/nginx/web

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

RUN cp -r dist/* /var/www/html

RUN chown nginx:nginx /var/www/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

`nginx_config` folder:

`default.conf`:

```
server {
  location / {
      root /var/www/html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        off;

    keepalive_timeout  60;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_proxied  any;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [jwilder](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) nginx resverse proxy, it will automatically create the Let's Encrypt certificates. I suggest you to use Docker Compose:

```
  your_container:
    image: your_image
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=your_domain
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=your_domain
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=your_email
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=port_you_want_to_expose

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "./vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./certs:/etc/nginx/certs"

  letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    volumes_from:
      - "nginx-proxy"
```

Just run `docker-compose up` and it will generate the certificates